# Call MahApps.Metro ShowMetroDialogAsync As Prism 6 InteractionRequestTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, mahapps.metro

I want to make use of Prism's interactions in conjunction with MahApps.Metro's custom dialogs. I was able to setup a MahApps.Metro style confirmation and notification windows. However, I would prefer this work like custom dialogs. I currently show (and hide) custom dialogs from the ShellViewModel by way of PubSubEvents. This methods works however when I need to capture the results of the custom dialog, I can't. Is there a way to merge these two concepts? Thanks!

Comment: This post is a bit old (3 yrs.).  If you still need an answer, let us know.  I am currently working on a similar situation using PubSubEvent from a module.  I might have a solution for yours.